# Ignore lines in errorformat

Tags: errorformat, eslint

I am writing a compiler plugin for eslint. It mostly works, but I want to ignore some lines in the output and am unsure how.

I'm using the eslint "unix" format, which outputs errors like so:

```
/Users/chris/Sites/build/web/test.js:1:1: Use the function form of 'use strict'. [Error/strict]
/Users/chris/Sites/build/web/test.js:2:3: Unexpected console statement. [Warning/no-console]

2 problems
```

Notice the blank line and "2 problems" line at the bottom.

My errorformat is this: `%f:%l:%c:\ %m`

This works, except I get the blank line and the "2 problems" line in my quickfix list, like so.

```
test.js|1 col 1| Use the function form of 'use strict'. [Error/strict]
test.js|2 col 3| Unexpected console statement. [Warning/no-console]
|| 
|| 2 problems
```

Reading the errorformat help docs, I see I can ignore some pieces with `%-`, but I'm unsure how to apply that to just blank lines or lines matching this "[number] problems" format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not an expert (hence a comment instead of an answer), but would assume `%-G%.%#` as the last part of `errorformat`. As I understand it, it means "ignore all that match `.*`. The other lines were already matched by previous parts.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Ralf! I think you're probably right that this is the direction to go, however using `%-G%.%#` at the end of errorformat gives me this error: `E377: Invalid %- in format string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
:set errorformat=%A%f:%l:%c:%m,%-G%.%#
```

The final `%-G%.%#` acts as a "catch all" clause, that ignores all lines, that are not matched by previous expressions.

The following should also work:

```
:set errorformat=%A%f:%l:%c:%m,%-G\\s%#,%-G%*\\d\ problem%.%#
```

Here

- `%-G\\s%#` ignores all lines that contains zero or more whitespaces. This inclues empty lines.
- `%-G%*\\d\ problem%.%#` ignores lines, that start with digits, a space and followed by "problem". I removed the final `s` and replaced it by `%.%#` (regex: `.*`), as I don't know if the s is omitted, when only one problem is detected.

The expression to match zero-or-more whitespaces (`\\s%#`) is different from zero-or-more digits (`%*\\d`). I'm don't understand why this is different.

Both formats tested with your example input.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! And thanks for the thorough explanation.