# Ignore lines with string in errorformat

Tags: python, errorformat

I'm writing a GitHub action that creates an annotation for files that would be reformatted when the [black python](https://github.com/psf/black) formatter is run. For this, to work, I want to parse the following example output:

```
would reformat /home/ricks/Development/personal/errorformat/fmts/testdata/resources/python/num_guess.py
would reformat /home/ricks/Development/personal/errorformat/fmts/testdata/resources/python/subfolder/queen_problem.py
Oh no!   
2 files would be reformatted.
```

From this console output, I want to match the first two lines which show which files would be reformatted. I do this by using the `%m %f` error format matching syntax. In addition to this, I would like to ignore the last two lies. After reading [this related post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18846/ignore-lines-in-errorformat) I came up with the following error format syntax:

```
%-G%Oh no!\ %m 
%-G%*\\d\ files%.%#
%m %f
%-Q
%-G%.%#
```

This syntax, however, doesn't seem to work as it keeps matching the last two lines as a message with a file name `%m %f`. You can see this syntax in action in the following [errorformat playground session](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/?efms=%25-G%25Oh%20no%21%5C%20%25m%20%0A%25-G%25*%5C%5Cd%5Cfiles%25.%25%23%0A%25m%20%25f%0A%25-Q%0A%25-G%25.%25%23%0A&text=would%20reformat%20%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fnum_guess.py%0Awould%20reformat%20%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fsubfolder%2Fqueen_problem.py%0AOh%20no%21%20%F0%9F%92%A5%20%F0%9F%92%94%20%F0%9F%92%A5%0A2%20files%20would%20be%20reformatted.%0A).

If anybody knows the right syntax for only matching the first two lines I would be really grateful. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few minor issues with most of your lines ignoring specific patterns.

1. `%-G%Oh no!\ %m` : You have an extra `%` there, turning the first character into a `%O` (a command to overread the matched part) rather than a literal `O`. You also have a trailing space there, so it would only match a line with a space at the end! You can fix that to `%-GOh no!\ %m`. Note that you don't actually need the `\` to escape the space in this format, you only need it when using the `:set` command, since it breaks on whitespace. You can also just use `%.%#` at the end of the line, since you're ignoring this pattern anyways.
2. `%-G%*\\d\ files%.%#`: Here you need a single backslash in `%*\d` to match a number. Note that this is using a `scanf()`-style pattern, you can also use a Vim regular expression here to match a sequence of digits, with `%\d\+`. You have one more issue on your playground for this one, you have no space before `files`, you have just `\files` over there, so that needs to be corrected too. Same as above, you don't need to backslash-escape the spaces here, only for a `:set` command.
3. `%-Q`: This is a command to pop the last file from stack, but this only makes sense when using a corresponding `%P` to match a file name relevant for a block of messages. It doesn't look like that's the case here.

Here's the [playground with minimal fixes](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/?efms=%25-GOh+no%21%5C+%25m%0A%25-G%25*%5Cd%5C+files%25.%25%23%0A%25m+%25f%0A%25-Q%0A%25-G%25.%25%23&text=would+reformat+%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fnum_guess.py%0Awould+reformat+%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fsubfolder%2Fqueen_problem.py%0AOh+no%21+%F0%9F%92%A5+%F0%9F%92%94+%F0%9F%92%A5%0A255+files+would+be+reformatted.%0AOneword.%0A) to make it work, and here's a [playground with more cleanup](https://reviewdog.github.io/errorformat-playground/?efms=%25-GOh+no%21%25.%25%23%0A%25-G%25%5Cd%5C%2B+files%25.%25%23%0A%25m+%25f%0A%25-G%25.%25%23&text=would+reformat+%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fnum_guess.py%0Awould+reformat+%2Fhome%2Fricks%2FDevelopment%2Fpersonal%2Ferrorformat%2Ffmts%2Ftestdata%2Fresources%2Fpython%2Fsubfolder%2Fqueen_problem.py%0AOh+no%21+%F0%9F%92%A5+%F0%9F%92%94+%F0%9F%92%A5%0A256+files+would+be+reformatted.%0AOneword.) (removing the spurious `%Q`, the backslash escapes spaces, using regex for the digit match and a `%.%#` to match the end of the "Oh no!" line.)

Comment: I can't believe I've never seen that playground… incredibly useful!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It really helped me clean up some gaps in my knowledge. You are a true vim (error format) master!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The playground is indeed amazing. I was delighted when I found it. The only thing you have to keep in mind is that it does not yet support vim regex syntax (see https://github.com/reviewdog/errorformat).